unable to mock out functions for testing
I'm somewhat new to mocking for unit tests.
I have some code like this:
In foo/bar/baz.py I have 2 functions I want to mock, one calls the other:
def function1_to_mock():
.    
.    
.

def function2_to_mock(): 
    function1_to_mock()

In foo/bar/main.py I import 1 of these and call it:
from .baz import function2_to_mock

def some_function(): 
    function1_to_mock()
    .
    .
    .

I want to mock both function1_to_mock and function2_to_mock
In my test I do this:
def function1_to_mock(kid): 
    return MOCKED_VALUE

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True) 
def mock_dependencies(): 
    with patch(foo.bar.baz.function1_to_mock') as mock_function1_to_mock, \ 
      patch('foo.bar.main.function2_to_mock') as mock_function2_to_mock: 
        mock_function2_to_mock.return_value = {
            'this': 'that
        } 
    yield mock_function1_to_mock, mock_function2_to_mock

def test_main(mock_dependencies): 
    some_function()

When some_function is called the real function1_to_mock and function2_to_mock are called instead of my mock.
Can someone please let me know how to properly mock these 2 functions.

I have modified a bit your code and I don't have used pytest but only the module unittest.
Your baz.py file has become (not far from your: I have added only the print instruction):
def function1_to_mock():
    print("REAL function1")
    
def function2_to_mock():
    print("REAL function2")
    function1_to_mock()

In your main.py I have changed only the import instruction as following:
from baz import function2_to_mock

def some_function():
    function2_to_mock()

I have created the file test.py in the folder foo/bar/test.py:
from main import some_function
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

def f1_mock():
    print('F1_MOCKED')

def f2_mock():
    print('F2_MOCKED')

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main(self):
        with patch('baz.function1_to_mock') as mock_function1_to_mock:
            with patch('main.function2_to_mock') as mock_function2_to_mock:
                mock_function1_to_mock.side_effect = f1_mock()
                mock_function2_to_mock.side_effect = f2_mock()
                some_function()

    def test_main_real_func(self):
        some_function()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


The output of the execution in my system is the following:
F1_MOCKED
F2_MOCKED
REAL function2
REAL function1
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK

The previous output shows that the test method test_main() calls the mocked function f1_mock() and f2_mock(), while the test method test_main_real_func() calls the real function (function1_to_mock() and function2_to_mock).
In this test I have used side_effect instead of return_value.
This is one of the possible ways to substitute real function with mock functions. I hope my code could be useful for you.
